# azure websites backup strategy

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

I have a simple azure website with a linked sql azure DB.  I want to be able to back up both the ftp files and the SQL DB.  What is the best option for this?  I know I can log into the ftp and just copy the files somewhere as well as a db backup.

**QUESTION:** Is there is a built in Azure backup process that I can **restore to a previous point**.
For example, If I update my code and break my site but don't know what happened, can I restore both files and DB to yesterday or 2 hours ago?  Does that make sense?

I have already read [this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/backup/) and it was no help

[This MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8c20d282-8711-4c48-9824-d691f5dcf747/taking-backups-from-azure-websites)  seems to indicate that this "restore point" is not available.

So I am looking for confirmation or other options

Thanks in advance

Comment: I disagree with this question being closed. There is valid, objective material that's being presented as answers. I can understand if the OP asked if Azure is better than another cloud provider, or something similar. However: This is an answerable question (e.g. SQL Database has import/export service; Web Sites have deployment history+rollback). This question, in my opinion, should be re-opened.

Comment: What I was asking was if there is a built in process within windows azure that can create a "restore point" for both the ftp and sql database together.  Stephane and David are right in saying no.  There are options for backing up and restoring the ftp and DB separately (which I now have implemented), but not combined together as I was asking.  I do not think this is opinion based as it can be answered yes or no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Azure does not include an integrated backup system that allows you to rollback to a previous version.

For the web site, the data is typically pretty small so it's pretty easy to SFTP or VPN into the web site and take a backup with a scheduled task.

For the SQL database, the simplest option is to use the SQL import/export service to dump the content of the database to a storage blob. Since that import/export is not transitionally consistent, you will need to first make a database copy and take a backup of that copy.

Other than that, there are a number of vendor who provide SQL azure backup services on premises or to cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows Azure Web Sites, and you set up source control (git, tfs, dropbox, bitbucket, etc.) then you can roll back your code to a prior deployment. You can view the history of all your deployments and choose any one to roll back to.

With ftp deployment, you won't have this option (but you can just zip up your code and archive it in a blob with, say, build-number as the blob name, in a "builds" container.